# fetch database records in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm learning [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html) From this link. I've a little confusion in fetching the data from database.

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></h3>
    <div class="main">
            <?php echo $news_item['text']; ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">View article</a></p>
```

While displaying the data in view they have used a variable `$news` in foreach loop. However this variable is never defined anywhere

Comment: `$news` should be an associative Array, and yes you are right, they should have defined in that tutorial ...

Comment: Yes, I know that but the problem is where it came from

Comment: If you learn codeigniter properly you will definitely get that this variable is associate with controller. it came from controller

Comment: when fetch the data from model then need to  save in a variable or array. In your case the variable/array is $news.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select)

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

// Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable
The second and third parameters enable you to set a limit and offset clause:

$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);

// Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20, 10 (in MySQL. Other databases have slightly different syntax)
You'll notice that the above function is assigned to a variable named $query, which can be used to show the results:

$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this hope this will give you what you want simply make a controller and call the associated model in the constructor and perform the function what your want it will return the array so you will be eassilly fetch and use it in your view.
**Controller code**

```
class TestController extends Controller{
    function __construct() {
                            parent::__construct();
                            $this->load->helper('url');
                            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                            $this->load->library('form_validation');                        
                            $this->load->model('User');             
            }
    public function index(){
    $data['all_user']=$this->User->getAllUser();
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
    }
```

**this is my model code**

```
class User extends CI_Model{
 public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

        public function getAllUser()
        {
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('users');
                    return $this->db->get()->result();
        }
}
```

just follow the steps 
make a controller 
make a function inside the controller 
call the associated model function into it and you will definately get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this `Controller` code ? (above the code that you pick, in the tutorial)

```
public function index()
{
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

`$news` is passed through as `$data` element from the `Controller` to the `View`